# How to change URL after post request in MVC 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, url

we made an web app using vs 2010 mvc 4, that displays product catelougue to users, we have also created cart system for the same. But whenever user submits cart We are displaying view, but URL remains same,

before posting data to action CheckOut URL is :

www.domain.com/shoppingcart/checkout

after posting data to action Checkout URL is same as mentioned. What I need to accomplish is Change  "www.domain.com/shoppingcart/checkout" this URL to "www.domain.com/products" so even if user refreshes the page He/she cannot place the same order Twice or more times.

my post method is form post. No ajax calls have been made to post form.

Any suggestions?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckOut(Order order)
    {
        try
        {
         //.. some code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleErrorInfo err = new HandleErrorInfo(e, "ShoppingCart", "CheckOut");
            return View("Error", err);
        }
        return View("OrderPlaced", order);
    }
```

Can I Do something like this?

```
[DisplayURL(URL="www.domain.com/Products/Catelouge")]
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckOut(Order order)
    {
        try
        {
         //.. some code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleErrorInfo err = new HandleErrorInfo(e, "ShoppingCart", "CheckOut");
            return View("Error", err);
        }
        return View("OrderPlaced", order);
    }
```

Comment: Show you controller methods.

Comment: You need to redirect, not return the view - `return `RedirectToAction(..)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke 
the View I am returning displays user about status of order. I can't redirect to another action from here! I need to redirect to products page after order placed view is rendered user accidentally or intentionally submits Data again to the method by either refreshing or going on previous page and then submitting order again –

Comment: What do you mean you _"I can't redirect to another action from here!"_ Of course you can and you need to. If you do not follow the standard PRG pattern then you will have this problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok I got It. But can you tell me that how do I detect that my controller action is being hit twice with same data..!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please see my edit for one more doubt..

Comment: But if your redirecting then you wont be hitting the action with the same data twice. Although I unsure where you should be redirecting - you question states you want to go to `/Products` but you code shows you returning a view named `OrderPlaced`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Now you got me, I want to return View `OrderPlaced` only but On that page but if user hits refresh or resubmits data I want him to redirect to `/Products` then.

Comment: It might be worth you looking at [nopCommerce](https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/) to see how its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was suggested by Stephen Muecke.

To use PRG pattern to redirect to another method or to avoid unnecessary calls to action methods. Thanks Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just redirect to a new page:

`return Redirect("Home/MyNewPage");`

Comment: the View I am returning displays user about status of order. I can't redirect to another action from here! I need to redirect to products page after order placed view is rendered user accidentally or intentionally submits Data again to the method by either refreshing or going on previous page and then submitting order again